# Bean of type EntityManagerFactory could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following Repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<User, String>, UserFilteringRepository {

}
```

```
public interface UserFilteringRepository {
    List<User> findWithFilters(String userId);
}
```

```
public class UserFilteringRepositoryImpl implements UserFilteringRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> findWithFilters(String userId) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before I attempted to gain access to the EntityManager, the application was working fine. The Repository was able to create, delete, get, etc for Entities.

However, adding the UserFilteringRepository and UserFilteringRepositoryImpl causes the following Exception on bootstrap:

```
Field userRepository in serverUserService required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I am using the spring-boot-starter maven dependencies & do not have an explicit hibernate dependency anywhere.

My understanding is that the Repository uses the EntityManager underneath, so I'm not sure why the bean isn't there given that the Repository on its own is working fine.

I have tried:

1. Specifying a different Hibernate version in Maven
2. Using @PersistenceUnit instead of @PersistenceContext to try to get direct access to the EMF

Answer (score 1):

I guess CassandraRepository does not have an @EntityManager. Instead, I found it was possible to autowire a CassandraOperations:

```
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;
```